# In R, find value in one CSV, isolate it in another

Tags: r, csv

I'm working on a project in R, regarding baseball. I have two CSV's that I'm working with. One file, CSV2: "PitchingPost.csv" is all postseason pitching stats, and the column I'm looking at there is the "teamID". I'm trying to evaluate regular season pitching stats in another file, CSV1: "pitching.csv" but only for teams that made the postseason. So I'm trying to remove all of the items in the "teamID" of CSV1 EXCEPT for those occur in CSV2 "teamID".

Help?

Comment: Sounds like a merge function thing. Check merge to join your datasets on teamID.

Answer (score 2):

To keep only the rows from your first file that share an ID with rows in your second file, you could try something like that:

```
pitch <- read.csv("pitching.csv")
pitch_post <- read.csv("PitchingPost.csv")

pitch <- pitch[pitch$teamID %in% unique(pitch_post$teamID),]
```